# iPhone application blank black screen on launch

Tags: iphone, xcode, storyboard

Hey so I have an application I am making that worked fine when I started, I am using xCode 4.5.2 and a storyboard. One day when I started developing a touch, when I ran the application, all that shows up is a blank black screen and it never pops into my storyboard. I start out of a tab bar controller and I do have "Is initial View Controller" checked. Is this a common problem? and if so what are a few solutions to it? It just bothers me because the same code was working the other day and I didn't remove anything from the delegate. Any suggestions would be very much appreciated,  thanks in advance!

Comment: Revert back to the code that was working and re-implement your changes.

Comment: its been a few days of me messing with it. can I still do that?

Comment: Depends when you committed your last changes to git or svn.